# Can I use a friendly URL on SearchAction?

Tags: url, schema.org, google-sitelink-searchbox

My current URL for searches is this one:

```
https://example.com/search/key/seach_word_here
```

JSON-LD

```html
<script type='application/ld+json'>
[
  {
   "@context":"http:\/\/schema.org",
   "@type":"WebSite",
   "@id":"#website",
   "url":"https://example.com",
   "name":"Example",
   "potentialAction":{
    "@type":"SearchAction",
    "target":"https:https://example.com/search/key/{search_term_string}",
    "query-input":"required name=search_term_string"
    }    
  },

  {
   "@context":"http:\/\/schema.org",
   "@type":"Organization",
   "url": "https://example.com",
   "name": "Example",
   "logo":"https://example.com/img/logo.png",
   "@id":"#organization", 
   "sameAs": ["https://www.facebook.com/example"]
  }

]
</script>
```

As you can see I'm using a friendly URL on the `target`.

I have seen people using a query string on the URL like this:

```
https://example.com/?search={search_term_string}
```

I did not see people using a friendly URL on the `target`. It's not allowed?

And at https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox it says:

> Verify your search engine implementation by copying the WebSite.potentialAction.target URL from your structured data, replacing search_term_string with a test query, and browsing to that URL in a web browser. For example, if your website is example.com, and you want to test the query "kittens", you would browse to `https://www.example.com/search/?q={kittens}`.

I tested this url `https://example.com/search/hey/{search_word_here}` and I got a 404 not found, but this URL worked: `https://example.com/?p=search&tp=key&word={search_word_here}`.

**So my question is**: Can I use a friendly URL on the `target`? And the code on my snippet is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you have to use **the URL that *works***.

Google will use the `target` URL for their Sitelink Searchbox, so that users can search on Google’s SERP and end up on your internal SERP. If you specify a `target` URL that leads to 404 pages, having this feature makes no sense, and Google would have no interest to enable it for your results.

If that URL happens to be friendly (e.g., without a query component), [so be it](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/102730/17633).

Comment: does the `target` URL really needs to work with `{}`? I got the 404 if i put this on the friendly url

Comment: @Natalie: Ah, I see. No, you have to replace the string *including* the `{}`. That part from the Google quote is misleading/wrong. So from your example, you should test `https://example.com/search/key/kittens` in the browser.

Comment: Got it, so my `target` and `query-input` on the snippet is correct? or should i replace `search_term_string` for something else?

Comment: @Natalie: Apart from the double "https", it seems to be fine (assuming that `https://example.com/search/key/kittens` works).

Answer (score 1):

Agree with above solution from @unor, now answering about you code correction

Please check the target url in posted JSON-LD:-

```
 "target":"https:https://example.com/search/key/{search_term_string}",
```

Remove the double https:

Also in case of JSON-LD: you cannot map name value to /{search_term_string}

A correct way is always like this:-

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "url": "[website url]",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "SearchAction",
    "target": "[website search url]={search_term}",
    "query-input": "required name=search_term"
  }
}
</script>
```

Microdata:-

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
  <meta itemprop="url" content="[website url]"/>
  <form itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchAction">
    <meta itemprop="target" content="[website search url]={search_term}"/>
    <input itemprop="query-input" type="text" name="search_term">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: How should i change this line? `"target": "[website search url]={search_term}"` i got this error on google structured data testing tool `INVALID_SYNTAX`.

Comment: @Natalie in that target you have to code for example test like this:-

`"target": "https://pinterest.com/search?q={test}",`
`"query-input": "required name=test"`